# Error when installing add-on

Tags: firefox-addon, manifest

I'm trying to install my example extension which has the following directory structure.

```
myexample
- install.rdf
- chrome.manifest
- content
-- myexample.js
-- myexample.xul
```

The file chrome.manifest contains:

> content   myexample  chrome/content/
>
> overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul 
>   chrome://myexample/content/myexample.xul

It's pretty minimalist extension.

I created a zip file from it:

`zip -r myexample.xpi myexample/`

When installing it in Firefox `Tools -> Add-ons -> Install Add-on from file ... -> choose myexample.xpi` it writes:

`This add-on could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt.`

Did I something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The title of your question is misleading - there is nothing wrong with your `chrome.manifest`. This error message rather means that Firefox couldn't find `install.rdf` file at the top level of your add-on. If you run `unzip -l myexample.xpi` you will see something like this:

```
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
                            myexample/
                            myexample/install.rdf
                            myexample/chrome.manifest
                            myexample/content/
```

As you see, all files you zipped have been put into the `myexample/` subdirectory instead of being at the top level of the archive. To get the correct result you need to run the following commands:

```
cd myexample
zip -r ../myexample.xpi *
cd ..
```